# Change event not fire if change comes from another function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some controls in form and I want to detect all changes of these controls regardless of whether user or vba made these changes.

I try this code (on combobox for example) :

```
Private Sub Combo3_Change()
 MsgBox "test"
End Sub

Private Sub Command0_Click()
 Me.Combo3.Value = 5
End Sub
```

It works if user made the change but it does not work if i click on the command button that make the same change.

I also tried after update event and it does not work.

Note: I have the same code in excel and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. `Control_AfterUpdate` never runs when the control value is changed via code.

If you want the code (typically `_AfterUpdate`, for `_Change` it usually doesn't make sense) to run, you need to call it yourself after making the change.

Comment: Thank You, my problem is that I have a lot of controls that changed from more than one function, I will try both yours and @Scott Jore suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You have to be very careful changing back and forth between Access and Excel forms.  They look very similar, but they each have their own form library and the events fire differently.  ComboBoxes can be especially troublesome in terms of trying to catch changes made.

One way to be sure that your code will always fire when a change is made is to create a property and change the property instead of the combobox directly when changing the value in code:

```
Private Property Let Fruit(vNewValue As String)
    Combo3.Value = vNewValue
    Combo3_Change
  End Property

  Private Property Get Fruit() As String
    Fruit = Combo3.Value
  End Property

  Private Sub Combo3_Change()
    Label5.Caption = Combo3.Value
  End Sub

  Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Fruit = "Grapes"
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You, I will try it but as my comment on @Andre answer I have a lot of controls.

Comment: I tested it (using Class module) and worked 100%, but it make things complicated, So I will simply call `change event` like @Andre's answer, thank You again for this great solution.

Comment: No problem, sorry it wasn't more helpful.